# Apache Camel - Getting xpath value from XML

Tags: java, xml, xpath, apache-camel, file-transfer

I'm trying to make a program by using camel. This program should  be able to recieve xml files in a folder called **inbox_xml_files**.

Then the program should get the text value of the **< Country >** element node inside the xml file.

If the text value is "Denmark" the file should be moved to a folder called "outbox_Denmark".

If the text value is "Sweden" the file should be moved to a folder called "outbox_Sweden".

If the text value is something else the file should be moved to a folder called "outbox_Other".

This is the XML file i use for testing:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
  <Employee>
      <FirstName>Mike</FirstName>
      <LastName>James</LastName>
      <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
      <Email>oy@hotmail.com</Email>
      <Address>
            <Country>Denmark</Country>
            <City>Copenhagen</City>
            <Zip>1234</Zip>
      </Address>
  </Employee>
</Company>
```

The camel xml file **(The one I'm troubled with)**:

```
<camelContext id="camelId" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <camel:route id="_route1">
            <camel:from id="_from1" uri="file:C:/inbox_xml_files?noop=false"/>
            <camel:choice id="_choice1">
                <camel:when id="_when1">
                    <camel:xpath>
                            //Company/Employee/Address/Country = 'Denmark'
                        </camel:xpath>
                    <camel:to id="_to1" uri="file:C:/outbox_Denmark"/>
                </camel:when>
                <camel:when id="_when2">
                    <camel:xpath>
                            //Company/Employee/Address/Country = 'Sweden'
                        </camel:xpath>
                    <camel:to id="_to2" uri="file:C:/outbox_Sweden"/>
                </camel:when>
                <camel:otherwise id="_otherwise1">
                    <camel:to id="_to3" uri="file:C:/outbox_Other"/>
                </camel:otherwise>
            </camel:choice>
        </camel:route>
    </camelContext>
```

I believe that the problem is inside the **< camel:xpath >**. I think i have defined it wrong and i'm trying but all this is something new for me so i'm struggling with it.

Comment: I don't think you need //Company, try /Company

Comment: Change xpath to `//Company/Employee/Address/Country[.='Denmark']`

Comment: Yeah or does `//Company/.../text() = 'Denmark' not also work, eg using text() to indicate the text in the xml node. In any way its standard xpath so go search the internet for some examples

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
<camel:xpath>//Company/Employee/Address/Country='Sweden'</camel:xpath>
```

or

```
<camel:xpath>//*[local-name() = 'Country' and text()='Sweden']</camel:xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding namespace in the input xml and define the same at route level. While accessing the value use the namespace prefix in xpath.

Incase namespace is not available use "*:" as prefix to access the xpath value.

```
<camel:xpath>
                        //*:Company/*:Employee/*:Address/*:Country = 'Sweden'
                    </camel:xpath>
```